# Run winform application with terminal command, with the configuration xml file given as command argument

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, command-line

The batch testing requires calling existing winforms application (say MyApp.exe) from the terminal, using the configuration stored in the .xml file in the same directory as .exe (say MyAppConfig.xml). Which changes should I make on the application in order to be able to call `start /realtime c:\MyApp.exe /config="MyAppConfig.xml"` from terminal. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction on how to implement this feature? Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your application's `Program.cs` file you'll find your applications entry point, `Main()` method. Change its signature and add `string` array which will hold parameters. Then, check for parameters and implement your logic.

Something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] startArgs)
{
    if (startArgs.Length == 0)
    {
        //show messagebox stating that there's no parameters or something else
    }
    else
    {
        var configArg = startArgs.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StartsWith("config"));
        if (configArg == null)
        {
            //config parameter is missing
        }
        else
        {
            string xml = configArg.Split('=')[1];
            //xml holds your path to your xml file. 
            //Now you can pass it to form, or load it here

            //XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            //doc.Load(xml);
            //etc...
        }

    }

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

If you plan to have multiple command line parameters, you should look for [NET CLI](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dotnetcli/) library which is .net port of the apache commons cli API, used for parsing command line arguments...

Comment: Thank you very much, very complete and clean explanation!

Comment: @MiroslavRadojević glad i could help. Sretno! ;)

Answer (score 2):

When building a console or forms application the Main method usually serves as the entrypoint for the code. It takes an array of strings as a parameter that gets passed down from the CLI.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Argument #{0} = {1}", i, args[i]);
   }
}
```

So running `program.exe FOO BAR` would result in :

```
Argument #0 = FOO 
Argument #1 = BAR
```

You could also use `program.exe config="MyAppConfig.xml"` notation to make the arguments order-independant, but you would have to do some parsing yourself.